# How to check application works with 3G internet?

Tags: android, android-emulator

How can i check my application works with 3G. since in my app I need to connect to a URL to get data.

Thanks

Comment: Actually I tested it on Nexus One with 3G, not working is there any solution for this.
thanks

Comment: Contact your mobile provider and ask them why the URL does not work on their network. Or, contact whoever provides the server referenced by the URL and ask them why it does not work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply
i don't need to write any seperate code to connect to URL, when 3G is used for connectivity ??

Is there any settings i need to do in manifest file or anywhere in the code.??
   
thanks